# Android Google Map Application(map not showing up)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I know there have been a number of questions about this topic, but the answers have not been of use to me. I have generated the key, added the fragment code, referred to the api key, but the screen is just grey as others have described with the lack of map problem. My code is below.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flymap_awc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.flymap_awc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyADeLIgFS42YPAPjUjODWj5nH4y_ZKVfBM"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Activity Java File

```
> package com.example.flymap_awc;
> 
> import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import
> android.view.Menu;
> 
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
> 
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {   static final LatLng
> HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);   static final LatLng KIEL = new
> LatLng(53.551, 9.993);   private GoogleMap map;
> 
>   @Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
>         .getMap();
>     Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
>         .title("Hamburg"));
>     Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>         .position(KIEL)
>         .title("Kiel")
>         .snippet("Kiel is cool")
>         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
>             .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
> 
>     // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
>     map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
> 
>     // Zoom in, animating the camera.
>     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);   }
> 
>   @Override   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>     return true;   }
> 
> }
```

The eventual goal is to use sensor listeners for rotation to move around the map, but first I just need to get the map to show up. If anyone can help point out what I am doing wrong I will greatly appreciate it. Thank You

Comment: I have an identical setup, running in my app. It works great, so this is odd. I suppose it's a given but have you tried to clean project / restart the phone? Sometimes things tend to be a but buggy if you build the application a 1000 times over. If this wont work, there may be issues with the API-KEY.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did try restarting my phone and cleaning the project but that doesn't work. My API-Key should be fine. Not sure what is causing the problem, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please post the logcat...

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below consideration which may help you:

> ```
> 1 . Have you turned on Google Maps Android API V2 in developer console?
> 2 . Are you using any new device where map has not been loaded yet, This might work as I had similar issue on a samsung device.
>  This might not be a concrete step but you can try
> ```

Thanks